# Jquery each html

Tags: jquery, html, each

I have code:

```
success: function( res ) {                  
    if( res.updated.length > 0 ) {
        $.each( res.updated, function( k,row ) {
            $( '.topStatsOuter' ).html( row.html );
        });
    }
}
```

When i try alert(row.html), I got all results, but when I use code as above. It adds only one result to div, why?

EDIT.

Tried **append**. My original div:
http://image.prntscr.com/image/3ac6dc5a137e46ababff6acd6bfc2a1a.png

After append:
http://image.prntscr.com/image/6b9a2fc093c0440a8d39afd8db0dc274.png
I want to overwrite, not add same code

Comment: Try `$( '.topStatsOuter' ).append( row.html );` - Because you currently overwriting the content of the element (When using `html()`). You can add `$( '.topStatsOuter' ).empty()` before the loop to remove any previous content

Comment: @AlonEitan tried, not works

Comment: Have you tried to empty the element `$( '.topStatsOuter' ).emtpy()` before the `$.each( res.updated, function( k,row ) {` line?

Comment: What is `res`? What is `.topStatsOuter`? What is `row.html`? Please add more details, so that we can reproduce your code.

Comment: @AlonEitan thank you so much ! Write post, I will mark it as answer

Comment: @EvaldasL Thanks. I added my full answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing at the moment is to overwrite the content of the element (`$( '.topStatsOuter' ).html( row.html );`).

What you should do is to first empty the content of the element and then append the results using the loop. Your code should be as follows:

```
success: function( res ) {                  
    if( res.updated.length > 0 ) {
        $( '.topStatsOuter' ).empty();
        $.each( res.updated, function( k,row ) {
            $( '.topStatsOuter' ).append( row.html );
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
success: function( res ) {                  
    if( res.updated.length > 0 ) {
        var html="";
        $.each( res.updated, function( k,row ) {
            html+=row.html;
        });
        $('.topStatsOuter').html(html);
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.